# Nginx Redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm struggling with a nginx redirect that I've set up.

Basically, I want to redirect /case-study/ to /case-studies/ but don't want to redirect any url past /case-study/*.

I have this setup already:

```
location = /case-study/ {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /case-studies/ permanent;
}
```

Which works for /case-study/ but also redirects any url after /case-study/test-url-redirect

Cany anyone help me out on this one.

Comment: Your config is already correct. Redirect is done somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to make it a regex location like so:

```
location ~ /case-study(/?)$ {
    return 301 /case-studies/;
}
```

Should match `/case-study` and `/case-study/` and redirect to `/case-studies/` but not redirect anything that is under `case-study`